# Prime of your life vs prime time of your life

Tags: expressions

Is there any difference between prime time of your life and prime of your life?

For example:

> 30s is the prime time of your life.
>   30s is the prime of your life.

Englighten me please.

Answer (score 1):

"**[the prime of your life](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+the+prime+of+life)**" is an *idiom* meaning "*the most healthy years of your life*".

"**[prime time](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prime%20time)**" is an expression originating from TV scheduling, meaning the hours in the evening where the largest number of people are watching TV (8pm to 10pm, let's say - the actual figures will vary from place to place and aren't important).

"**The prime time of your life**" isn't an expression in regular usage.    Since its a novel (to most people) phrase, people would interpret it differently, but I think most people would take it to be a witty combination of the above two phrases.  The meaning might be guessed to be

a) similar to "prime of your life", ie the most healthy years, or

b) the most exciting time of your life, eg where you're partying all the time with no responsibilities.

or something else of course.